# Form Request Validation on validation fail trying to print all the request data

Tags: php, validation, request, laravel-5.5

I created From Request Validation in my controller here all sets fine and working but when error comes then i want to print the request data in the view.blade.php with

```
Request::all()
```

this return `empty []` Although i want all the form data into it.

Please Assist

Thanks

My contoller's Method code to store data looks like

```
/**
    * Store non capital expense
    *
    * @return null
    * @param $request store expense
    */
    public function store(StoreExpense $request) 
    {
        $request->flash();
```

AND Create method

```
/**
    * non-capital expenses
    *
    * @return null
    * @param crops Get the all crops
    */
    public function create(Crops $crops) 
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has old() helper to retrieving "Old" input. For example

```php
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

This method helps you to print previous request input values if validation failed.

Comment: But i am using the dynamic inputs fields in the foreach loop

Comment: old('field_name') did the trick for me and i managed it in the loop. Thanks